# Using Jersey to POST to service - "A message body writer ... was not found"

Tags: java, xml, service, client, jersey

I've written a basic RESTful service using Java/Jersey for managing subscribers, and now I'm trying to create a client to talk to this service, but I'm getting a run-time error I don't understand. Here is a trimmed down version which exhibits the problem:

Subscriber class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Subscriber {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Subscriber() {
    }

}
```

Main test app:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;

public class MyTestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        WebResource service = client.resource(UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost:8080/MyService").build());

        Subscriber s = new Subscriber() {{
            setFirstName("John");
            setLastName("Doe");
        }};

        System.out.println(service.path("subscriber")
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .entity(s)
                .post(String.class));
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class MyTestClient$1, and MIME media type, application/xml, was not found
```

It's unclear to me exactly what this error message means; it appears to be something to do with the conversion of the subscriber to XML (although, to me, the error message implies it's trying to convert MyTestClient, which can't be right...) I've used the same Subscriber class in my service, and it has no problem creating XML to send to the client, so I'm rather confused.

If I replace the Subscriber object with a string containing the XML, I don't get the error message, but I want to use objects, for many reasons.

What is the cause of this error message, and how can I fix it?

**EDIT:**
For reference, although I'm not sure it's relevant, here is the relevant part of the service side of the code:

```
@POST
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Subscriber post(Subscriber subscriber) {
          /// doesn't get here
    }
```

Also, this works, but isn't using the Subscriber object:

```
    String xml = "<subscriber><firstName>John</firstName><lastName>Doe</lastName></subscriber>";

    System.out.println(service.path("subscriber")
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .entity(xml)
                .post(String.class));
```

**UPDATE:**
I can work around the problem by explicitly converting my object to a string first, thus:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Subscriber.class);
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
m.marshal(s, sw);
String xml = sw.toString();

System.out.println(service.path("subscriber")
.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
.entity(xml)
.post(String.class));
```

but that's rather messy and I don't see why it should be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "A message body writer for Java type, class MyTestClient$1" is reporting that it's trying to marshall an anonymous inner class. We'd normally expect to see "class Subscriber". You're probably loosing the JAXB annotations when doing this new Subscriber() {{}}.

My first recommendation would be to pass the name to a constructor which would be cleaner and not make you loose the JAXB annotations.

```
Subscriber s = new Subscriber("John","Doe");
```

or alternatively call the default constructor and then set the fields afterwards:

```
Subscriber s = new Subscriber();
s.setFirstName("John");
s.setLastName("Doe");
```

If you need to define an anonymous inner class, then you can try to reannotate @XmlRootElement before your new anonymous class definition. (never tried it though so your mileage may vary :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the String.class argument specifies the type of the response, not the request.  post(s) (without the .entity() part) results in the same error. Even if it worked it wouldn't be too helpful, because that variant of post has a void return, so I couldn't get at the response.

Comment: sorry you're right, I jumped to conclusion spotting this difference in your two pieces of code. I'll update my answer with my next suggestion.

Comment: Aha!  I was wondering what the MyTestClient$1 was. I'd not considered the fact that the Subscriber initialision notation I used creates an anonymous subclass (I'm more used to C# where a similar notation is used for object initialisation without constructing a subclass). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There can be two problems:

1. Make sure the consumes annotation is set on top of your REST web service method handling this request: @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
2. Secondly your bean seems to be missing the annotation on the getters. Here is your udpated bean:

@XmlRootElement
public class Subscriber {

```
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

@XmlElement (name = "firstName")
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@XmlElement (name = "lastName")
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Subscriber() {
}
```

}

Comment: The \@XmlElement annotations make no difference. The class is serialized to XML perfectly well by the service without those annotations - it's only the client that has the problem.   The service already has the appropriate \@Consumes annotation.  Also, as stated in my question, if I replace the subscriber object with a String containing the XML, the service responds correctly to it. Added the relevant bit of the service to my question as a reference.